# UITextView starts scrolling from the top when adding text

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

```
            NSString *tempText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You've acquired some food %i\n\n", foodCount];
            infoLabel.text = [infoLabel.text stringByAppendingString:tempText];
            [infoLabel scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([infoLabel.text length], 0)];
```

So I'm having trouble getting the autoscroll to work in the UITextView. Adding text to this UITextView works fine until it goes further than the size of the UITextView, at which point it snaps back to the very top of the text view before scrolling to the bottom.

```
 ---------------
|    line1      |
|               |
|    line2      |
|               |
|    line3      |
 ---------------

     line4
```

Say the box is as big as shown, if i add line 4 to the UITextView it snaps back to line one and then scrolls down instead of scrolling a little bit to show 4 If anyone can shed some light on this that would be great!